# Combine curl and base64 into one command?

Tags: shell, quoting, command-substitution

I'd like to POST the Base64 encoding of a file to a server, combining `curl` and `base64` into one command that I can execute. I've tried the following:

```
curl 'http://localhost:5000/files' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"file": "$(base64 hello.txt)"}'
```

But it just POSTs the string literal `"$(base64 hello.txt)"`, instead of substituting the result of executing `base64 hello.txt`. So how do I do it properly?

Comment: If you try `curl 'http://localhost:5000/files' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"file": "'"$(base64 hello.txt)"'"}'`? (that is, "unquote" the bash command `$(...)` but protected by surrounding by double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use simple quotes, nothing is interpreted:

```
~$ echo 'foo:$var bar:$(base64 foo) something'
foo:$var bar:$(base64 foo) something
```

You have to unquote if you want the interpretation:

```
~$ echo 'foo:'$var' bar:'$(base64 foo)' something'
foo:foo bar:Zm9vCg== something
```

And since you don't know what it can contain, it's better to double quote:

```
~$ echo 'foo:'"$var"' bar:'"$(base64 foo)"' something'
foo:foo bar:Zm9vCg== something
```